# Backup USB Drive with windows backup

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, backup, windows-backup

I use an external SSD (SSD in mount case) for swap use. I, however, mostly use it for home use. The problem is that windows update won't allow me to add this device to file history, although he's is connected to the PC most of the time. I am getting the following error: "

Image:

[image: that image]

Translation:

`Create a backup of these directories`

`Unfortunately  that won't work. If you would like to know more, search for error code 0x80070032`

`Add a directory`

I tried searching for this error, but no answer suited what I needed. Searching for "Window backup of USB Drive" didn't give me any answers either.

In case you need specs:
OS: Windows 10
SSD: Samsung 970 EVO 1TB

Comment: What format is the target drive's file-system?  How did you prepare the drive for File History usage?

Comment: exFAT, I did not prepare it

Comment: I believe the drive needs to be formatted as NTFS before File Histories will work.  Format it, remove all partitions, and then unplug and replug.  Windows should offer to set it up, including for File History work.